# Find minimum value from comparing specific columns, but show all columns and rows - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I want to find the minimum value from comparing specific columns, but show all columns and rows. I hope this example makes it clearer.

This is my data:

```
+----+----+-----+-----+
| PK | FK |  A  |  B  |
+----+----+-----+-----+
|  1 |  1 | abc | tzu |
|  2 |  1 | def | qwe |
|  3 |  2 | abc | tzu |
|  4 |  2 | def | qwe |
|  5 |  3 | def | qwe |
+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Now, I am looking for the minimum value of PK (Min_PK) by comparing columns A and B (duplicates) for each row. The result should look like this:

```
+--------+----+----+-----+-----+
| Min_PK | PK | FK |  A  |  B  |
+--------+----+----+-----+-----+
|      1 |  1 |  1 | abc | tzu |
|      2 |  2 |  1 | def | qwe |
|      1 |  3 |  2 | abc | tzu |
|      2 |  4 |  2 | def | qwe |
|      2 |  5 |  3 | def | qwe |
+--------+----+----+-----+-----+
```

I tried several thing:

```
SELECT MIN(PK) AS Min_PK, `table`.`A`, `table`.`B`
FROM `test`.`table`
GROUP BY `table`.`A`, `table`.`B`;
+--------+-----+-----+
| Min_PK |  A  |  B  |
+--------+-----+-----+
|      1 | abc | tzu |
|      2 | def | qwe |
+--------+-----+-----+
```

This just returns the duplicates, but not all columns and rows. If I add PK and FK to GROUP BY, it will compare all columns for duplicates.

This is getting closer:

```
SELECT
    MIN(PK) AS Min_PK,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`table`.`PK`),
    GROUP_CONCAT(`table`.`FK`),
    `table`.`A`,
    `table`.`B`
FROM `test`.`table`
GROUP BY
    `table`.`A`,
    `table`.`B`;
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----+-----+
| Min_PK | GROUP_CONCAT(`table`.`PK`) | GROUP_CONCAT(`table`.`FK`) |  A  |  B  |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----+-----+
|      1 |                        1,3 |                        1,2 | abc | tzu |
|      2 |                      2,4,5 |                      1,2,3 | def | qwe |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----+-----+
```

Here I have all the information I want, but it is not the right form. I want it separated by row.
Could you help me with this issue?

**---------------------------------------
EDIT:**

The code of Giorgos Betsos is working on this problem, but for big tables it has a poor performance. This is why I want to add some more Information.

In my case, i want to use the code for a large table with around **20 columns** and more than **500k rows**.

If I use:

```
SELECT
    MIN(PK) AS Min_PK,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`table`.`PK`),
    GROUP_CONCAT(`table`.`FK`),
    `table`.`A`,
    `table`.`B`
FROM `test`.`table`
GROUP BY
    `table`.`A`,
    `table`.`B`;
```

it is super fast. It takes only a few seconds to get all the information. But unfortunately in the wrong form.

If I use the code of Giorgos Betsos:

```
SELECT t2.Min_PK, t1.*
FROM `test`.`table` AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(PK) AS Min_PK, `table`.`A`, `table`.`B`
   FROM `test`.`table`
   GROUP BY `table`.`A`, `table`.`B`
) AS t2 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
```

It is the right form and result, but it takes a lot of time because of the subqueries + 20 JOINS....

Another problem is that there are NULL values in some columns, so the JOIN doesn't work....

Any ideas?

Comment: It may seem counterintuitive, but in my experience labelling columns PK and FK doesn't really aid comprehension.

Comment: @Strawberry : Yes, you are right. Sorry for that. But in my case PK and FK are indeed primary and foreign keys. So yes, I have a lot of duplicate data in my database...

Comment: Appropriately indexed GB's solution will be blisteringly quick

Comment: @Strawberry : Sounds good, Thanks. But what do you exactly mean by that. Should I index each column?

Comment: Well, I think I mean a covering index on (a,b,fk)

Comment: Ah, ok. I see. Unfortunately, MySQL is restricted to 16 columns for a covering index...
But indexing each colmn enhances performance as well. But now I have the next problem....
I have NULL values in my database, so the JOIN does not work... Any Idea?

Comment: If a covering index is required to cover more than three or four columns, that kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design. Indexing each column will have very little benefit, as MySQL can only choose one index per table instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your first query as a derived table and join back to the original table so as to get the rest of the fields:

```
SELECT t2.Min_PK, t1.*
FROM `test`.`table` AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(PK) AS Min_PK, `table`.`A`, `table`.`B`
   FROM `test`.`table`
   GROUP BY `table`.`A`, `table`.`B`
) AS t2 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks for your help! It is working.

I will adapt this to my database and report how it is going.

Comment: I tried this code on my database. Unfortunately, I have performance issues now. I will edit my post to give more details in a few moments. Maybe you can have another look. Thanks

Comment: Hi Giorgos, when I add indexes, the performance of your solution is much better. BUT, I have NULL values in my database, so the JOIN does not work... Any Idea?

Comment: @Uli The question is markedly different now from the one which was originally asked - plus there's little incentive to answer questions with 'accepted' answers. I suggest you ask a new question, referencing this one.

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks, I will do that!